# JQGrid Column name from Table

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Am working on JQGrid and i got this doubt on how to implement.

Currently am displaying standard set of results to user every time as given in examples.

```
colNames:['Inv No no NO','Date', 'Client', 'Total in EUR']
```

Suppose if am changing this result set i will change in .js file (add or remove column) of JqGrid.

Is there a any way i can bring these Column names from Table and Bind it to JqGrid ?

Also how do i ADDcolumn names at runtime ? like adding new Column  and all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside `loadComplete()` try the following code to change the column name dynamically to a value.

```
 $("#grid_id").jqGrid('setLabel',"column_name", 'new_label');
```

You can parse the `colModel` to get to the particular column you wish to change to do the same.

Comment: am talking about bringing column names from DB and adding column not changing the Column text

Comment: Though can dynamically set the columns, you cannot add new columns if or when required if the grid already has a set of data